# How to save a page in PDF with a single click in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, print-to-pdf

I would like to accomplish to **save a page in PDF** with a single click in Google Chrome.

Basically have a **button or keyboard shortcut** which allows me to save a page as PDF in one single action. I want exactly the same behavior and output as the normal printing to PDF which comes with Chrome by default but I don't want it to show print preview, ask for settings and filename. I want it to save it with the **page title** in a default location.

I've tried several extension but didn't find any that works as I need.

Comment: Which extensions were tried?

Comment: @Pro, please don't abuse formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FireShot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg) Chrome Extension. It allows you to save the whole page or the visible part of a page to a PDF or a image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but it's not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

I built something like this specifically for Gmail called [Duffel](https://getduffel.com/). One of our users linked me here, so I thought I'd mention it